# How can I make this kind of grid programmatically with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm new to Java. I want to create a game grid that I can interface with some logic code.

I was able to make it using Netbean's GUI builder tool (only partially shown, but the same pattern repeats up to say 10 x 10). However I am not yet familiar with creating complex layout in code.

[image: grid (partially shown)]

Problem is, it looks like it's going to be a lot of repetitive work hooking up each of the buttons to array elements in my game logic as there doesn't seem to be a way to configure arrays of buttons in the GUI builder.

(Each set of buttons of a kind has it's own array.)

Can someone show me how I might create the same kind of grid purely in code? I'm guessing GridBagLayout is what is needed. (The alignments between the different types of blocks is important.) But looking at code examples there are seem to be a lot of concepts involved and it seems to be a bit too much to take in at once. I'd appreciate being started off in the right direction.

Alternatively if there's a way to efficiently do this in the GUI builder tool I would like to hear about it.

Comment: *"..there doesn't seem to be a way to configure arrays of buttons in the GUI builder."* That's why most of us prefer not to use GUI builders (or at least, one of many reasons). I'd use `GridBagLayout` for that, making sure to use the `GridBagConstraints` to stretch components to the width or height for the 'bits between the squares'. Oh, and probably a 'factory method' would be useful in there as well, given the repeating patterns..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm hoping someone will chime in with some skeleton code that I can flesh out. (Maybe too much to hope for but...)

Comment: *"I'm hoping someone will chime in with some skeleton code.."* I have, on many occasions, given complete code to do a certain task.  But that is typically ***only*** when I've already seen the attempt from the person asking the question, in the form of a [mcve]. The ball's in your court..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I appreciate that, and how you want to help someone is definitely your prerogative.. the kind of thing I had in mind is kinda the other way around. I just wanted someone to start me off so I could see the various patterns I need to know and extrapolate from there. If I sit down to figure it out from scratch I'll probably manage it myself without needing help from Stackoverflow.

Comment: *"..so I could see the various patterns"* You mean *design patterns*? My code is typically entirely free of them (or any 'design' for that matter). Except by accident.  ;)

Comment: No, not design patterns.. I'm not explaining myself properly. I guess I just wanted some sample code that shows how the specific constraints might be put in for this kind of grid. I know the info is all out there, just wanted to shave an hour or so off reading time - lol. My brain is at information overload stage atm (not referring to Java). But I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices, you could use compound components in some way, for example, it seems to be a repeating pattern, so you could isolate a single "tile", focusing on the layout needs for a single tile and then use a different layout manager to physically layout the tiles or using something like `GridBagLayout` to layout all of them.

Which you use will come down to what it is you want to achieve and the functionality you are trying to produce

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
                gbc.gridy = row;
                for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                    gbc.gridx = col;
                    if (row % 2 == 0) {
                        if (col % 2 == 0) {
                            add(bigButton(), gbc);
                        } else {
                            add(verticalButton(), gbc);
                        }
                    } else if (col % 2 == 0) {
                        add(horizontalButton(), gbc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected JButton bigButton() {
            JButton btn = new JButton() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }
            };
            return btn;
        }

        protected JButton verticalButton() {
            JButton btn = new JButton() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(45, 100);
                }
            };
            return btn;
        }

        protected JButton horizontalButton() {
            JButton btn = new JButton() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 45);
                }
            };
            return btn;
        }
    }

}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Wow, looks brilliant.. thanks a lot! (haven't tested it yet though - I'll do it in a bit). I had the idea of compound components myself; would tiling together a 2d array of JPanel's each containing the three-block set work? How would I deal with the asymmetry at the ends (I'm guessing I could make some buttons invisible)?

Comment: I'm just sorry I can't upvote you yet (not that you're hurting for rep lol)

Comment: You could write a "start", "middle" and "end" components

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "write components" you mean by subclassing JComponent, correct?

Comment: or `JPanel`, but yes